# Is there a way to format blogger.com posts the same way I do in stackoverflow?

Tags: markdown, blogger

For syntax highlighting, [Syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) seems the best solution. But is there an engine to format blog posts with the same markdown as stackoverflow, because I find it quite usefull, especially the inline code (with ``), and the blockquote.

Can I find such a plugin for blogger.com ? Else, I think I will stick with Syntax highlighter.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but are you looking for pagedown http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Comment: Looks promising. I'm interested if there is a easy way to integrate with blogger.com.

Comment: Looking for the same thing, I meet a blog post: [Markdown in Blogger](http://blog.chukhang.com/2011/09/markdown-in-blogger.html)